# Excel formual Stepping in shows "䀁" incorrectly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am evaluating a formula here

> `=SUMPRODUCT(Rate_0,--(Rate_1=$Q$10)*--(Rate_2<=$D13)*--(Rate_3="x"))/$B$15`

in excel. `Rate_n` is a defined range I have. When I step into the `--(Rate_3="x")` part, I get:

[image]

(Some of the screenshot is blurred for confidentiality)

Most notably, the `䀁` charachter shows up in the evaluation. I am not sure why this is here and how to get rid of it. Or how to properly evaluate my formula.

Comment: So they tried to remove the [8192 characters limit](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1319163-problem-in-evaluation-of-formula-with-f9.html) but failed.

Comment: @GSerg can you expand on that?